# My WIN32 API dialog box dosent show - C++

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

Hello I'm attempting to learn how to create Windows Apps using the WIN32 API.  To this end I am going through The Forgers Tutorial on the subject.  I am stuck at trying to get my first dialog box to show up when my menu item is clicked.  I have checked out the MSDN site and looked at the documentation on all relevant functions in my code and everything APPEARS correct TO ME.  But, of course, I don't know because I'm just learning I wonder if anyone can point out my error or perhaps point me in the direction of what I may be missing in the documentation.  I'm sure that it's something really dumb (as it always is with these things)
at any rate here's my little script.  Hopefully any of you can help. Thanks

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "WindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                LPSTR lpszArgument,
                int nFunsterStil)

{
HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

/* The Window structure */
wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

/* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
/* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

/* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
    return 0;

/* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
       0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
       szClassName,         /* Classname */
       "Windows App",       /* Title Text */
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
       544,                 /* The programs width */
       375,                 /* and height in pixels */
       HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
       NULL,                /* No menu */
       hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
       NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
       );

/* Make the window visible on the screen */
ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);

/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
    TranslateMessage(&messages);
    /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
    DispatchMessage(&messages);
}

/* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
return messages.wParam;
}
/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
{
    case WM_CREATE:
         {
             HMENU  hMenu, hSubMenu, hOtherMenu, hOtherSubMenu;

             hMenu = CreateMenu();
             hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
             hOtherMenu = CreateMenu();
             hOtherSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
             AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_FILE_EXIT, "E&xit");
             AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&File");
             AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_STUFF, "S&tuff");


             AppendMenu(hOtherSubMenu, MF_STRING,ID_OTHER_SUB, "O&ther");
             AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hOtherSubMenu, "&Other");


             SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu); 
             //SetMenu(hwnd, hOtherMenu);

             }
             break;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
         MessageBox(hwnd, "this is my program", "program box", 0);
         break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
         DestroyWindow(hwnd);
         break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
             case WM_COMMAND:
         switch(LOWORD(wParam))
         {
             case ID_STUFF:
                 DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUT), hwnd, AboutDlgProc);
                 break;

             case ID_FILE_EXIT:
                  PostQuitMessage(0);
                  break;
         } 
    default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
BOOL CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
 switch(message)
 {
     case WM_INITDIALOG:
              return TRUE;
     case WM_COMMAND:
              switch(LOWORD(wParam))
              {
                  case IDOK:
                   EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
break;
case IDCANCEL:
EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
break;
}     
break;
default:
return FALSE; 
}
return TRUE;
}
```

this is the .rc

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>

    IDR_MYMENU MENU
    BEGIN
    POPUP "F&ile"
    BEGIN
       MENUITEM "E&xit", ID_FILE_EXIT
       MENUITEM "stuff I like", ID_STUFF
    END
END    


IDD_ABOUT DIALOG DISCARDABLE 0,0,239,66
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About Box"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON "&ok", IDOK, 174,18,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON "&Cancel", IDCANCEL, 174,18,50,14
    GROUPBOX "About this program...",IDC_STATIC,7,7,225,52
    CTEXT "This is a Modular Database program", IDC_STATIC, 16,18,144,33
END
```

and this is the header for the .rc

```
#define IDR_MYMENU 101

#define ID_FILE_EXIT 4001
#define ID_STUFF 4002

#define IDC_STATIC -1
#define IDD_ABOUT 102
#define ID_OTHER_SUB 4003
```

P.S. I am a first time poster to any forum at all so I apologize if I didn't get the code in clearly please just let me know Thanks again!

Comment: Send NULL instead of HWND_DESKTOP and see what happens. Also try to use SW_SHOW instead of nFunsterStil and see what happens.

Comment: Thank You very much for the response! I tried both of the changes together and seperatley and still the dialog does not show when the button is clicked.  Just to be safe I tried a simple call to MessageBox as well in place of the call to DialogBox and it worked.

Comment: I'm confused about what isn't working. When I compile and run this code, exactly as shown, I get a window on the screen with the title "Windows App" and a menu bar containing "File" and "Other" menus. When I click on the "File" menu, and then select "Stuff", I get a dialog box that's titled "About Box" and it has an "ok" button. What's different about that when *you* try to run it?

Comment: Although as another person has commented already, `HWND_DESKTOP` is certainly incorrect and should be replaced with `NULL`. You're doing the right thing by passing `nFunsterStil`, though.

Comment: When I Click on the "stuff" button I get no response at all! strange... BTW this is a great community with good people who respond to questions with good info quickly I hope to one day know enough to help someone else here!

Comment: @user1390368 in the build menu, clean the solution, recompile, and try it.

Comment: jonaton and all, I failed to mention earlier that I am using DEV-C++ instead of MSVC++, sorry.   I was not able to find a solution to my problem except that i should use MSVC++ and resource editor... However I was able to find a Work-Around by simply creating another standard window that when created set the enable to false on the parent window by following instructions I found here. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/245377/windows-api-dialog-will-not-show.-un-solvable-  Thanks all for your help I hope this will help someone in a similar situation.

Comment: Your dialog procedure should return `FALSE` for unhandled messages. Yours is returning `TRUE`, which prevents default window actions from occurring (e.g. creating your window!)

Comment: Check the return value of `DialogBox()`, if it's -1 it failed...

Answer (score 1):

i think you didn't add `resource.h` and `recource.rc` to your project.

if you don't add them your project will compile but dialog-box will not shown.

I compiled your code and it worked fine.

i use mingw4.7 and devc++ IDE.

[image: After add]

[image: Before add]